# Creating Mutiple Command Prompts through Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

So, I am trying to create a batch file that will do the following

1. Run on startup(which I know how).
2. Ping
3. Ping
4. Traceroute to Hostname and Hostname's IP every 5 minutes.
5. Create daily logs of all results.

Unfortunately, I am familiar with Batch Files only, so if anyone has any better suggestions I would love to hear them.

Here are my computer stats:

Host: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit
Vmware Player 7 Pro Free(Non-Commercial Use)
Vmware Guest: Windows XP Pro SP3

Only reason I am using XP is because I am having conflict video driver issues with the graphics card.. It is running on a driver that is designed for XP only, so if I am not careful I will get a BSOD on my Win & host.

If I could even acheive the same function in CentOS that would help out a lot as well(seeing that I can just do it CLI).
Anyways, I have the following portion:

```
@echo off
ping -t 
call C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /K "ping -t 192.168.255.255"
```

I want each command to open in its own window. Like the ping in one window. Ping in another, and every 5 minutes the traceroute will pop up and run in a 3rd command prompt window.

I also tried(commands below) but I can't get a new window to pop up.

`start cmd "ping -t 192.168.255.255"`

`start cmd /K "ping -t 192.168.255.255"`

`cmd "ping -t 192.168.255.255"`

`cmd /K "ping -t 192.168.255.255"`

I've read numerous forums, syntax, and I am not able to find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`start` by itself will open the command in a new window

`start "" ping -t 192.168.255.255`

The initial `""` is because `start` considers the first set of quotes to be the window title, and this is the workaround for that.